# What is involved in a WSL "distribution"?

Tags: windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux, distribution-choice

WSL allows the user to use any distribution of their choice, and Ubuntu is installed by default.

I don't really understand the relevance of the distribution in the WSL context. My understanding is that Linux distribution refers to the skin of the OS. A UI layer on top of the OS core. But when using WSL you just use the command line, or perhaps run an independant single gui application. So what is the relevance of distribution in this context, and what difference does it make which distribution you choose?

Comment: Here is my guess. Distributino is a collection of: drivers, Cli tools and ui skin (desktop). Distribution on WSL is all of those, but the ui skin isn't relevant.

Comment: Not really drivers; in WSL the syscall layer is coming from the Windows kernel, so there's no Linux kernel at all.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy While true at one point, that's now a bit outdated.  Yes, WSL1 uses a syscall translation layer, but WSL2, which has been the dominate version for two years now, uses an actual Linux kernel in a managed VM.  The kernel is still provided by WSL2, though, so agreed that WSL (either 1 or 2) doesn't use the one (or its drivers/modules) that comes with the distribution.

Comment: You seem to be conflating UI with GUI.  The command-line user interface provided by the distribution is what you're concerned with here.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> My understanding is that Linux distribution refers to the skin of the OS. A UI layer on top of the OS core.

That's not correct. Linux distributions differ in many fundamental ways which go beyond the look&feel of the GUI:

- versions of the kernel, plus various customizations (Want the latest kernel and cutting-edge software? Use Fedora. Want stability? Use RHEL.)
- support for different hardware devices
- package managers (RHEL has `rpm`, `yum`, and `dnf`; Debian has `dpkg` and `apt`; ArchLinux has `pacman`; and so on)
- software packages and tools (Debian, for instance, has only free and open source software in its main repo)
- repositories, with different timelines for updates and bugfixes

However, if your main use is just writing some Bash script, your experience will be more or less the same regardless of the distro.

Comment: This is very helpful. Is the Kernel one package, or a collection/composition of packages?

Comment: @BenCarp It depends on the distribution, and what you consider the kernel. Firmware is usually in a separate package (even though on Windows that would be part of the drivers themselves), and some distributions have the kernel modules in a separate package from the kernel itself.

Comment: "If your main use is just writing some bash script, your experience will be more or less the same" -- this assumes a relatively mainstream distribution, as opposed to something like NixOS (where `/usr/bin` has no file other than `env`, and `/bin` has no file other than `sh`) or GUIX.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Strongly agree - Even on WSL.  I spent way too many hours last weekend trying to bootstrap GUIX on WSL as a hobby project (was partially, but not totally successful).  I may take another look at it later, but I came away pretty convinced that GUIX's eschewing of the FHS makes running it on WSL a bit too challenging at this point.  We can blame that on WSL, or GUIX, or just the combination of both, but they don't get along all that well.  I'll probably look at NixOS on WSL (for my education) at some point as well, but I haven't yet.

Comment: *"Want the latest kernel and cutting-edge software? Use Fedora."* -- Just realize that, on WSL, the kernel in Fedora is *not* applicable or used.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds You can try [Gentoo](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Gentoo_in_WSL) instead of Fedora. Possibly even more cutting edge. Also a bit more of a learning curve.

Comment: @doneal24 My point is that the *kernel* from Fedora (or Gentoo, or xyz) isn't utilized in WSL (which this question is about), *regardless* of the distribution being used.  As an unrelated side-note, I did use Gentoo for about 3 years a while back (before WSL), and it's definitely a good distribution.  Ultimately, I moved away from it because (at the time at least) it just involved too much "tinkering" (a.k.a. constant "learning curve") to keep running.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds I have not played with WSL since it is blocked my work environment and I did not realize that MS provided a generic kernel for all distributions. Learned something new today. :)

Comment: @doneal24 Understood - That's one of the reasons why I asked the OP to post over here on U&L (vs. Stack Overflow where it was originally posted, but off-topic).  It's a question that can benefit from the viewpoints/answers of both *Linux* experts as well as *WSL*-specific knowledge.  Just as more information - WSL2 is really more like running in a Docker (or lxc, or other) container on Linux -- It's using the kernel from the *host* (the managed WSL2 VM) rather than the image (a.k.a. "distribution" in overloaded WSL-speak).

Comment: Note that even just using bash different distros can behave differently. Some embedded distros (Roku, TiVo, some router based distro etc.) don't even include bash but use busybox instead. Some distros have abandoned bash and use alternate shells by default (fish, zsh etc.)

Comment: In short, "distribution" is what makes Linux (which is kernel) to become a "real" OS.

Answer (score 20):

Some other answers here have focused on the "normal" meaning of a "Linux distribution", which is certainly useful to understand as background for your question.  But you are asking about it specifically in the context of WSL.

> what difference does it make which distribution you choose?

Let me answer that part of your question first, before we get into the "differences" regarding distributions on WSL.  The main differences in Linux distributions are going to be (focusing primarily on the WSL/developer needs here):

- Versions of applications available in the default repositories.  There are (to over-summarize) typically two *types* of distributions that you will find:

  - "Stable" distributions, which tend to update very infrequently (other than security updates) but focus on making sure (to the best of their ability) that all packages work together well and don't break the system.  Ubuntu, Debian, and Red Hat are good examples of these.

    Ubuntu, for example, has one release every 6 months.  But only every two years (in April of even numbered years) is it updated with a long-term support (LTS) version (e.g. 22.04 LTS), which is supported for 5 years.
  - "Rolling-release" distributions, which focus on getting new releases of software into their repositories as soon as they are considered stable and tested.  Arch and Kali are common examples of these.

  openSUSE, as another example, has distribution releases for *each* model, and both are available as Microsoft Store installs for WSL.  If you search the Store for openSUSE, you'll find both "Leap" releases (stable) and "Tumbleweed" (rolling).

  Whether you choose a Stable or Rolling release is really up to you.  I keep both around, personally.  There's no reason at all on WSL to limit yourself to just one distribution (other than disk space).  I've used Tumbleweed as my rolling release for a while, with the latest LTS of Ubuntu as my stable.  However, I've been impressed with Artix as a rolling release (based on Arch) and am probably going to be trying it as my daily-rolling-driver for a while.

  Also note that, as a developer (from the fact that you posted this first on Stack Overflow, as well as your profile there), it may not matter quite as much for you based on the languages and tools you use.  You appear to do a lot of Node-based/React/web/framework development from your SO tags.  Under WSL (or any Linux distribution), you're unlikely to use the pre-packaged, repository version of Node.js anyway.  You're going to install via `nvm` or `n`.  Then, of course, you'll install packages/modules via `npm`, `yarn` (or other).

  And even for languages which are critical to the system and shouldn't be changed (e.g. it's a bad idea to change the Python version in a Linux distribution), you can use Docker or other virtualization/container technologies to use different language versions on WSL, regardless of the distribution.  (More reading on that topic - See my recent answer regarding Docker Python on the Ask Ubuntu question [How do I install a different Python version using apt-get?](https://askubuntu.com/a/1424207/1165986)).

  So, as a developer, if you don't have any non-developer reasons to go with a rolling release, a stable-style distribution *might* make your life easier in the long run.
- Availability of documentation and support is another good reason to choose a distribution.  It's on this basis that I simply have to recommend Ubuntu to most new WSL users (and it is, as you mention, now the default WSL distribution).  Most blogs, videos, or other instructional documentation that you find are going to focus on how to do things in Ubuntu.  This may be shifting somewhat to Arch, but for now I think the advantage in this camp still goes to Ubuntu.

  That's not to say that you can blindly follow any Ubuntu (or any distribution) documentation and have it work on WSL.  There are a number of differences in WSL that mean you often need to tweak the instructions somewhat.  Some of those differences are covered below, but I try to maintain a more complete list in [this Ask Ubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1409552/1165986).

  On the flip side, note that Kali is an advanced distribution, even when *not* in WSL.  See the excellent meta post here, *[If you need to ask, then Kali Linux is not the right distribution for you](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5361/432493)*.

> So what is the relevance of distribution in this [the WSL] context

In WSL, the word "Distribution" is actually a bit overloaded, with several meanings, as well as some important differences from the "normal" definition of *Linux distribution*:

- First, a WSL distribution, at its core, is simply a *packaged root filesystem*.  It can include something as simple as a *single statically linked executable* (like BusyBox) or a complex ecosystem of packages, scripts, and package management (like Ubuntu or Arch).

  That package can be a:

  - `tar` or `tar.gz`
  - A Hyper-V virtual disk image (`vhd` or `vhdx`) in the latest WSL Preview releases.

  But really, as long as you can package your files in one of those two forms, you can, at least `wsl --import` the package into a WSL distribution.  There are some convenient (and presumably tested) distributions available to install from the Microsoft Store into WSL, but they ultimately package an `install.tar.gz` which *then* gets installed into WSL.

  WSL's packaging has the added advantage that it is *really* easy to convert any software for which there is a Docker image to a WSL "distribution".  Just `docker pull ...`, `docker run ...`, and `docker export ...` to create a tarball.  Want a Red Hat image that isn't in the Microsoft Store, just grab the appropriate Docker image.  BusyBox?  Same.  Etc.

  To be a "bootable" distribution, however, you do need a minimum of:

  - An `/etc/passwd` with one or more users.
  - The shell defined for the primary user, which becomes the default entry point.
  - If the user is not `root`, then you either need a `/etc/wsl.conf` defining the default user (see [here](https://superuser.com/a/1627461/1210833)) or a registry entry.
- A "normal" Linux distribution also typically provides a default:

  - Init system
  - Kernel with drivers
  - Bootloader (typically GRUB2)
  - X and/or Wayland server

  None of that is needed or utilized in WSL.  WSL provides its own kernel.  While (in WSL2 at least) you can build your own (from standard kernel sources) and replace it, a single kernel is shared among all distributions that you have installed on your Windows/WSL system.  In WSL1, this is a pseudo-kernel that does syscall translations from Linux to Windows.  In WSL2, it is a real *Linux* kernel running in a managed (as in, you can't typically see it, access it, or change it) Hyper-V virtual machine.

  WSL also provides its own init system, which handles the interoperability between WSL/Linux and the Windows layer (such as networking, the ability to execute Windows binaries through `binfmt_misc`, WSLg boot, and more).

  This can be problematic, since WSL does *not* run the standard init for most Linux distributions.  For instance, even though Ubuntu/Debian/Arch (pretty much everyone other than some niche distros) runs Systemd, WSL does not enable it, even when running one of those "distributions".  See my explanations [here](https://superuser.com/a/1719430/1210833) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1379567/1165986).

  And while Systemd is, of course, the dominant init system, it is more problematic than most other init systems under WSL since both WSL's init and Systemd vie to be PID1.  Systemd will flat out refuse to run as anything but PID1 (and WSL2 won't let it, without using namespaces as a workaround).  Some other inits / process managers can run as non-PID1, so are more (IMHO) suitable for use under WSL.  I've had good success with Artix and Dinit, for instance.  And as a plain-vanilla process manager, [Supervisord](http://supervisord.org) works reasonably well under most any distribution.
- A WSL "Distribution" can also mean the "instance" or "container" that is created from the imported package.  Running `wsl -l -v` will list the installed distributions on your system.

  When you run one of these, at least under WSL2, what is running is essentially a container (isolated namespace) for the package you imported.
- A Linux distribution also often comes with a default Desktop environment (e.g. Gnome, KDE Plasma, Xfce, others) as well as (as you mention) theming.  While it's possible to run a desktop environment from your a distro in WSL, it's not a standard process.  In Windows 11, WSL can run Linux GUI applications through the use of the WSLg feature, but that's for running individual Linux applications integrated into the *Windows* desktop.

  Running a Linux desktop environment *can* be done (either through third-party X server, WSLg full-screen Weston/Xwayland, or XRDP) but (with the exception of XRDP) you'll need to make sure that keybindings for things like <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> are changed so that they don't get intercepted by Windows built-in functionality.

Comment: Also important: the package manager used, the default shell

Comment: @Esther Fair points -- I had a feeling that someone would comment on package manager, and I deliberately did not discuss that topic since it was already addressed in at least one of the other answers (which I mention in the intro is good background for understanding the WSL-case).

Comment: As far as default shell, I'm not terribly sure it matters enough, does it?  Changing the user shell is typically simply a matter of installing through the package manager and doing a `chsh`.  And if you mean the system shell, then my personal opinion is that, while I know there can be differences between different POSIX shells, they are so negligible as to be corner-cases for most people.

Comment: But thinking of BusyBox in the context of shells does remind me that some distros (e.g. Alpine) do take a different `libc` approach, and that may be a more substantial difference that *hasn't* been mentioned (in either my answer nor any of the others).

Answer (score 6):

In a broad term, the difference in distributions is a difference in skin. The different graphic interfaces is just a special case of it.
Primarily, there are two major differences between any two distributives:

1. what is included inside the repository and what is not included;
2. what are defaults for the basic tools.

The example for the first could be a version of libraries or applications. Once developer make a new version - the maintainer of the distributive should download it, compile, and publish in the repository. If the maintainer (who is a real person) is expecting a lot of bugs in the new version of the application - he can skip that version. But the maintainer of another distributive will publish it as is and allow regular users to complain about bugs directly to developers.

For the second: in Ubuntu, the `sudo` is checking the group `wheel` for the list of users who is allowed to use `sudo`. In Fedora, that group is named `sudo`. That difference is built into the tool `sudo` during its compilation before it is put in repository as one of the basic tools.

And please do not forget, that the terminal is also a UI. Just not graphical. And there too could be differences. For example: in Ubuntu, you are using `apt` to install new applications from its repository, but in Fedora you are using `dnf` for the same task. That can be viewed as different UI choices. They have the very same purpose and almost the very same abilities and limitations. Just different set of command line keys and are working with packages of different structure.

With a good understanding of OS structure it is possible to ignore which distributive you installed and mix different approaches from different distros. You can recompile `sudo` yourself and define its special group as `admins` for example. Or you can install `dnf` on Ubuntu (or `apt` on Fedora) and download applications from both repositories, you would probably have to adjust some settings of the downloaded application afterwards, but it is possible.
And of course, you can always download some application/library as a source code, and compile it yourself, and share the compiled version - that would become you own distributive.

That apply to both - normal setup of OS and a WSL one.

Answer (score 4):

The distribution is the collection of software, which not only influences look and feel, but also availability of packages and maintainance thereof. A package you want to use may not be available on some distribution.

If you installed ubuntu via WSL you have to take care of updating the packages like on a VM ( `apt update` + `apt upgrade`).
Some other distributions may be faster or slower at providing patches (or maintaining packages at all).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure if this is "the" answer to your question, but different distros can have different kernel requirements at a given point in time, causing WSL1 compatibility to differ across distros.

As a practical example, Arch Linux suffered from the ["kernel too old" problem](https://github.com/yuk7/ArchWSL/issues/190) for a while due to a change in glibc-2.33-4, whereas Ubuntu didn't.
However, this issue [also came up on Arch containers on CentOS](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/69663), so it was not specific to WSL1 per se. But practically speaking it meant you would have more difficulty getting Arch running on WSL1.